# Where is the process and why aren't all the processes showing?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process

I am very new in Linux and Ubuntu and I have been using Windows before. I can find any running process there but here I can't.
I have ran KeePass and try to find it in processes but I couldn't. I looked it up in both [System Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i59Tm.png) and by `ps aux` but the process or something like that wasn't there.
How can it be and how can I find it?

Comment: Can you include the output of your command line? Have you tried `top`?

Comment: In your screenshot, it looks like it is not running, just as Chrome is not running.

Comment: Under **System Monitor** -> **View** did you select **All Processes**? Also, try `ps -efl | grep -i keepass`. If neither of these finds anything, then it's not running.